# Packagist: "create-project" from fork loads original repo

Tags: github, fork, composer-php, packagist

I'm just trying to grasp the concepts of dependency managers and GIT systems, so it's very possible I'm missing something very basic.

I use [ROOTS/BEDROCK](https://github.com/roots/bedrock/) project as a base of my Wordpress projects. It allows to use Composer with Wordpress (by adding Wordpress itself as a dependency) and various other awesome features. It is installable as a Packagist package by command `composer create-project roots/bedrock`.

However to make it fit with my Wordpress framework, I needed to do a light customization of the project. So I forked it and submited the fork to http://packagist.org with entirely new composer.json file.

What I do not understand is why composer after command `composer create-project myaccount/forked_bedrock` installs original repository and not my fork.

### TL;DR

Is it possible to submit a **forked GitHub repository to Packagist** and **use the fork** (not the original repo) by `create-project` command?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no package registered under the name "myaccount/forked_bedrock" on packagist.org. But to answer your question: Yes, it is possible. But depending on the customization, there might be better ideas.

Comment: `myaccount/forked_bedrock` was just an example, Sven. :) The original project is `cibulka/wpgrouse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem lied within **Composer cache** - after I've cleared it, Composer loaded the forked GitHub repository (not the original).

If Composer caches so "heavily", it would be nice if there was some option to clear/flush the cache, but apparently [there is nothing built-in](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/941) ...

Answer (score 0):

in my case was that i had to change the name of the package in the composer.json, changing the "name" propierty f